# Multiply two vectors in Calc element-wise

Tags: emacs, calculator

```
2:  [0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.125]
1:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Suppose, this is how the stack looks like, what I'd like to be the result of multiplication:

```
[1 * 0.5, 2 * 0.25, 3 * 0.125, 4 * 0.125]
```

Instead, Calc translates every value on its axis and then finds the distance (I don't need the last step, only the multiplication). How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Vector Map* command applies operations to vectors element-wise.

In your example, typing `V M *` will apply a multiplication to each element of the input vectors.

Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Mapping.html).

Comment: Does it have an algebraic form?